# get a node value from json file

Tags: json, facebook, linq

I am working on a facebook graph api project and have this json file:

```
     {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "407356746023254_569534706472123", 
      "from": {
        "category": "Furniture", 
        "name": "`enter code here`", 
        "id": "407356746023254"
      }, 
      "message": "message", 

      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/407356746023254/posts/569534706472123"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/407356746023254/posts/569534706472123"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "value": ""
      }, 
      "type": "photo", 
      "status_type": "added_photos", 
      "object_id": "569534676472126", 
      "created_time": "2013-12-03T22:54:45+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2013-12-04T15:29:03+0000", 
      "shares": {
        "count": 1
      },
```

I am working with  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq to parse this file

my code:

```
 For i = 0 To o("data").Count - 1
         Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(data)
    Response.Write(o("data")(i)("shares"))
next
```

the code result is  {"count": 1 }

I want to get only the value "1" from

```
"shares": {
        "count": 1
      },
```

but I can't

I think I missed the concept in someway . Any body can help?

Comment: you don't parse parts of a json string. You parse the ENTIRE thing back into a native structure. your loop cannot ever work because you're trying to 'for' on a STRING.

Comment: I have got the message text with the same for loop code

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 0 To o("data").Count - 1
    Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(data)
    Response.Write(o("data")(i)("shares")("count"))
next
```

This may help you... :) ;) :P

Comment: whenever i try(o("data")(i)("shares")("count")) i got Object reference not set to an instance of an object error